# output of the programme

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(void)
{
    int s = 0;
    s++;
    if(s == 10)
        return;
    f();
    printf("%d ", s);
}
int main(void)
{
    f();
}
```

what is the output of the programme!??
i m segmentation fault ...what is it?

Comment: What's stopping you from running it ?

Comment: Then the output is a segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not statically initializing `s`. So it'll **always** start off as 0 every time you call `f()`, and `f()` keeps calling itself over and over again but `if(s == 10)` is never met. The call stack eventually overflows and boom, segmentation fault.

Answer (score 6):

Since `s` is a local variable, each recursive call to `f()` gets its own copy of it. So every time `s` will be 1 and the you get a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling `f` recursively, without changing anything each time.  You're probably getting a stack overflow.

Each time you call `f`, you initialize `s` to `0` and increment it. It will never reach 10.

What you should do is either make `s` a parameter to `f` or else make `s` static.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is an infinite loop; you get the segmentation fault because you eventually overflow your stack.

Answer (score 1):

The program goes into an infinite loop.
The reason for that is :
s is local to f(), so  whenever f() is called, s is initialized to 0. Then it is incremented by 1, & f() is again called. This time as well, f() uses its local copy & initializes s to 0 & again calls f() recursively. This generates an infinite loop & the program generates a segmentation fault. The reason for seg fault is stack overflow due to recursive infinite calls.
To remedy this, either make s static or make it global, rather than local.

Answer (score 0):

How about making your variable s static?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function that calls itself. However, it is an infinite loop because `int s = 0;` resets the counter every time it is called. It will print an endless line of 0s.

Sample solution:

```
int main (void) {
   f(0);
}

void f (int s) {
   if (s == 10)
      return;
   printf("%d ", s);
   f(s++);
}
```

I'm not good with C syntax, but the idea is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop. Here is probably something similar to what you want

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int s)
{
    s++;
    if(s == 10)
        return;
    f(s);
    printf("%d ", s);
}
int main(void)
{
    f(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more interesting program:

```
void f(int s)
{
  s++;
  if(s == 10)
    return;
  f(s);
  printf("%d ", s);
}

int main(void) 
{
  f(0);
}
```

That will print:

`9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

Comment: Or you could have just make declared `static int s = 0;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The output of this program is the name of this site.

As others suggested you should declare `s` as `static int s = 0`